# Loading different descriptions within PHP array

Tags: php

I really couldn't find a good way to title this so I apologize if it's misleading, but what I'm trying to do is I have badges that players earn and I want them to be able to click on the badges and based on the badge they click get a different description to load using jquery. I already have it partly working, but the problem I'm having is it only gets the last badge's info. I know why it does this (I think, php is loaded first in page, and it'd need to be an array. Or maybe I just sound really dumb, haha) Here is what my code is so far:

```
    <table id="table-profile" width="78%">
  <tr>
    <td><h3><?php echo "$usernameprofile";?>'s Badges (work in progress!!!!!!!) |  <a href="#">View All</a></h3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?  
 $sqlbadges = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM membersbadges WHERE username='$usernameprofile' LIMIT 8 
 ");
 $checkbadges = mysql_num_rows($sqlbadges);
 if($checkbadges == "0"){
     echo "User is currently badgeless";
 }else{
?>
<table width="100%">
<?php
$tableCount = 0;
    $tableRowOpen = false;
    while($rowbadge = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlbadges)) { 
    $bid = $rowbadge['badgeid'];

    $getbadge = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM badges WHERE id='$bid'");
while($rowbadge2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getbadge)){
$badgeid = $rowbadge2['id'];    
$badgename = $rowbadge2['name'];
$badgedesc = $rowbadge2['description'];
$badgereward = $rowbadge2['reward'];
$badgerequirements = $rowbadge2['requirements'];
$badgepic = $rowbadge2['image'];
$date = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($rowbadge2['date']));

}
        if($tableCount == 0){
            echo "<tr>";
            $tableRowOpen = true;
        }
        echo"<td width='25%'>";
        echo  "<badge".$badgeid.">
<img src=\"http://my.iheff.net/images/badges/".$badgepic.".png\" border=2 alt=\"
        " . $row["name"] . "\" height=40px width=40px></a></badge".$badgeid.">" ;

        echo"<br/><br/></td>";
        if($tableCount + 1 == 4){
            $tableCount = 0;
            echo "</tr>";
            $tableRowOpen = false;
        }
        else{
            $tableCount++;
        }

    }
    if($tableRowOpen){
        echo "
</tr>
";
    }
    echo"
    <table id='badgeinfo".$badgeid."' style='display:none' width='80%' border='0' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='10'>
  <tr>
    <th colspan='2' scope='col'>".$badgename."</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Description:</td>
    <td>".$badgedesc."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reward:</td>
    <td>+".$badgereward." Experience</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    ";
?>
</table>
<?
 }
 ?></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<script>
$("badge<?php echo "$badgeid"?>").click(function () {
$("#badgeinfo<?php echo "$badgeid"?>").toggle("slow");
});    
</script>
```

Sorry for the messy code, I'm nowhere near a php whiz. But, I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here's an example page if you want to see how the page looks live. http://my.iheff.net/profile.php?id=1637

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're closing the `while` loop too quickly.  (It's looping through all the records, and assigning them, but not rendering them.)  So put all the badge rendering logic inside this loop:

```
while($rowbadge2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getbadge)){
    $badgeid = $rowbadge2['id'];    
    $badgename = $rowbadge2['name'];
    $badgedesc = $rowbadge2['description'];
    $badgereward = $rowbadge2['reward'];
    $badgerequirements = $rowbadge2['requirements'];
    $badgepic = $rowbadge2['image'];
    $date = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($rowbadge2['date']));

    // render the row here
}
```

To fix the Javascript issue, you could add the Javscript inside the loop, but it's probably better to add attributes to the *badge* tags:

```
echo  "<badge".$badgeid." data-type='badge' data-id='".$badgeid."'">"
```

That way you can use a single (static) block of Javscript to construct the click events:

```
// select all the badge tags
$("[data-type=badge]").each(function() {
    // get the id for the current badge
    var thisId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(this).click(function() {
        $("#badgeinfo" + thisId).toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would I call the first badge's description though? Like where I have <badge>*badge info* </badge>. Right now it will let me only call the 2nd badge's info on both badges.

Comment: For some more info, I want page to start showing nothing about the badges, but once you click on one jquery will have the description slide down under the badges. I think what you suggested would work if I was already showing all the descriptions, but I want them to be shown all separate. If you look on the link for the example it might explain it better. Or maybe I just completely misunderstood your response. haha

Comment: @iHeff gotcha - I think the best thing would be to add attributes to the `bagde` tags.  Say `data-type=badge` (to select all the badges) and `data-id=1` (to build the link).

Comment: Can I trouble you to provide a simple example of that? I'm not familiar with how that'd work.

Comment: I'm unable to test that out right now, but tomorrow I will and let you know if it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Funny how it all seems so obvious now haha. But thanks so much, you are a saint! All I have to do is fix some formatting and it'll be beautiful. Kudos to you!